How to get a BigQuery or Vertex AI scheduled notebook to log an error to Logs Explorer when a run fails with an error?
Whenever I set up a schedule in Vertex AI or in BigQuery orchestrator to run a Colab Enterprise Python notebook, if any of the notebook runs fails, I can see a general one-sentence error description when hovering on the run result:

But it's almost always the same non-descript "Error code 3: Error encountered during cell execution." which in no way helps me understand why that run failed.
I can open the Logs Explorer and filter errors by the job for that run, but there are no errors there, as if the job ran successfully.
Is there any way to create an error in Logs Explorer and just copy into it all the traceback of the python error that occurred when running the notebook?
I feel like that should be the default behavior and I shouldn't need to look for ways to enable logging of errors that occur during scheduled job runs.

I tried to reproduce the issue and effectively I see:
Error code 3: Error encountered during cell execution.


I clicked View Result to get more details about the error, in this case the Python error.

  File "<ipython-input-1-3aba69f82f7e>", line 1
    print(12
            ^
SyntaxError: incomplete input

Does that work for you?

Yes it does. I thought that this pane just displays the code I ran, cause any output was hidden by default and I didn't realize I need to press the Show output button. The errors aren't logged though, so if anyone finds a way to answer the original question, then it will probably be useful for others

I see, we execute the code in the same Docker container as you normally would do in Colab. When you say: "cause any output was hidden by default " are you referring to Colab setting "Omit code cell output when saving this notebook" can you please expand? I can think of enabling logging for Python code executed inside container and that may be shown in Logs. Will this work for you? If so I can submit a FR internally and update you here when ready

I mean the button under code blocks with executed code that says "Show hidden output"
